# socket.io NodeJS express and mqtt

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am using the express, mqtt and socket.io packages..

In fact socket.io works perfeclty fine as long as I use http instead of https.

However, whenever I change to https socket.io does not fire any action at all

I got:

```
       var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
```

Any clues?

Comment: Whenever I change the conncetion to http it works. Is it possible that socket.io does not support https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:

```
   var io = require ('socket.io').listen(server);
```